# how to get user details in WooCommerce site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a simple WordPress site with WooCommerce, and i would like to get logged user id and/or mail.

i'm pretty new to WP and PHP, so i guess i'm missing something elementry.

this is the main PHP Code:

```
<?php

//Needed?
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-customer.php';

class MyClass
{
    protected $wp;


    public function initialize()
    {

       if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Put your plugin code here

        global $woocommerce;
        $cust = $woocommerce->customer;
        echo '<div id="UserDiv" >';
        echo var_dump($cust); //returns NULL
        echo $cust->ID; //returns nothing
        echo $cust->user_email; //returns nothing
        echo '</div>';


        }

    }
}


?>
```

also tried:

```
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
```

and it didn't work either...

Thanks!

Comment: `get_current_user_id()` returns an ID?

Comment: get_current_user_id() returns  0

Comment: You are logged in? And where you include this code in wordpress. And show us the code which's produce the output, and tell us from where you call it.

Comment: the code above is in the "src" folder, and has a "MyClass.php" file
the main php file (bootstrap.php) has a this code:
    <?php  
    $MC = new MyClass(); 
    $MC->initialize();
    ?>